# Hide select option based on character in value on page load

Tags: javascript, ios, html-select, hide

I'd like to be able to hide or strip options from a select box based on content. The content of the select box is populated by a database which I have no access to, so the only solution is to hide the field. Easily done in most browsers, but android and IOS ignore the display:none in css.

Here's the code:

```html
<select id="variant2" name="variant2">
<option value="Size" selected="">Select Size / Option</option>
          <option value="SMALL|15004">SMALL </option>
          <option value="MEDIUM *|15005" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">MEDIUM *</option>
          <option value="LARGE *|15006" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">LARGE * </option>
          <option value="XLARGE|15007">XLARGE </option>
          <option value="2XL|15008">2XL </option>
          <option value="3XL|15009">3XL </option>
         </select>
```

Basically I want to disable / hide / remove the options that contain an asterisk in the value (*) as they're sizes that are out of stock.

Is this possible?

Comment: Note that you can't hide an option cross browser. Notably not supported in IE or Safari either.  Remove or disable are the choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the `option` elements, iterate over them, and check if the strings include `*`, if so, apply the styles.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("option").forEach((x)=>{
 if(x.innerText.includes("*")){
     x.style.display = 'none';
            x.style.visibility = 'none';
        }
})
```

```html
<select id="variant2" name="variant2">
    <option value="Size" selected="">Select Size / Option</option>          
    <option value="SMALL|15004">SMALL </option>
    <option value="MEDIUM *|15005">MEDIUM *</option>
    <option value="LARGE *|15006">LARGE * </option>
    <option value="XLARGE|15007">XLARGE </option>
    <option value="2XL|15008">2XL </option>
    <option value="3XL|15009">3XL </option>
 </select>
```

Edit: If you don't want to apply css, you can remove the elements using `removeChild()`:

```js
let variant2 = document.getElementById('variant2')
let children = Array.from(variant2.children)
children.forEach((x)=>{ x.innerText.includes("*") && variant2.removeChild(x) });
```

```html
<select id="variant2" name="variant2">
    <option value="Size" selected="">Select Size / Option</option>          
    <option value="SMALL|15004">SMALL </option>
    <option value="MEDIUM *|15005">MEDIUM *</option>
    <option value="LARGE *|15006">LARGE * </option>
    <option value="XLARGE|15007">XLARGE </option>
    <option value="2XL|15008">2XL </option>
    <option value="3XL|15009">3XL </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you I'll give it a try. I already have js to apply the css, but it won't hide the values in IOS or on Android, so this could be a godsend!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the list of options in JavaScript and output the items that don't contain the asterisk to your `select`.